# Custom Lock Screen Sometimes overwrite by stock lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I had developed a custom lock screen application. Basically when the screen is off, the application will launch and unlock the stock lock screen and then when the screen is on, user will see my custom lock screen. So far is working nicely until recently I discovered that sometimes when I press home button, the screen will blink once very fast, and when this happen, it will fail my custom lock screen. The stock lock screen will appear when screen on and my custom lock screen will only show up after user unlock the stock lock screen. Anyone has clue on this issue? or any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > security > screen lock and select 'none'. Now it should always show only your custom lock screen.